# How get Site Template name in SPSite, and Web Template name in SPWeb using C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, site-template, web-template

I`m trying to analyse sharepoint site.

In SPSite Level, I want to get Site template name,

and In SPWeb Level, I also want to get web template name.

But I am a newbie in SharePoint, I`m not sure how can I find those things.....

Please somebody help me, explain about it or give some link about it

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SPWeb.WebTemplate property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplate.aspx)
Gets the name of the site definition or site template that was used to create the site.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Test
{
   class ConsoleApp
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
         {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("sites/blog"))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Site definition: {0}", web.WebTemplate); // BLOG
               Console.WriteLine("Web template ID: {0}", web.WebTemplateId); // 9

               Console.WriteLine(web.WebTemplate == SPWebTemplate.WebTemplateBLOG); // True
               Console.WriteLine(web.WebTemplateId == (int)SPWebTemplate.WebTemplate.Blog); // True
            }
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

[For powerShell check this](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/finding-site-template-names-and-ids-in.html)